# Earth's rotation along it's axis

Tags: opengl, rotation

I've modeled an earth using an sphere. I can rotate it using `glRotatef` function around z axix by incrementing the angle. How do I simulate earth's movement which looks like 23.5Degree around Z axis? (see this [image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aPlanet_axis_comparison.png))

I guess I need to calculate the x,y,z verctors. Any Idea? I'm a complete newbie in computer graphics programming.

Comment: Research quaternions and axis-angle rotation.

Comment: you have to describe the earth's coordinate system after the 23.5 degree rotation and use axii from that coordinate system to feed the glRotatef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After applying the `glRotatef` to get the z axis rotation for time-of-day, call `glRotatef` again to get the tilt on the y (or is it x?)